# Modify ELF binary to extend array size

Tags: c++, linux, assembly, diff, binaryfiles

I have an ELF32 binary file, a game, that creates a stack of size 32 that gets filled with gamepad inputs when the game launches. The gamepad I want to use has 48 inputs which causes a stack overflow and the game crashes. I've asked the developers if it was possible for them to increase the stack size to 64 but they said that they have no plans to update the game any more. An old forum post had a link to a `bspatch` file that patched an older binary to update the stack size but that file is no longer available, leaving the only remaining option: I need to patch the game myself.

I don't really know where to begin. I have some `gdb` and `readelf` dumps but I don't know if those would be helpful to anyone who might be able to steer me in the right direction, though I will post them below anyway.

I guess the long and the short of it is, I need to know how to find the right object and modify its size. If there is any more information that I can provide that would help narrow down where I need to patch, I'd be glad to give it.

https://gist.github.com/karai17/da3b84949443761e2409f4ddba3eb17e (gdb dump)

https://gist.github.com/karai17/785d21bf863e9d24b25a744d2f25cfcf (readelf dump)

Edit: After some discussion, I've been pointed to the code in question and disassembled it via gdb. At this point I need to figure out which bits of assembly need to be adjusted, but I have never really delved into assembly before so it is a very slow process.. Any help would be appreciated. :)

https://github.com/chrismingay/CM-XMAS-2012/blob/master/xmas.build/glfw/main.cpp#L2895-L2935 (C++)

https://hastebin.com/uwejuvowat.asm (asm)

Comment: I doubt you will be able to do that. A utility may be able to pathch the stack segment size of a binary. A stack segment of size 32 would not be enough to sneeze, much less to run a game. The game most likely has some kind of data structure of size 32 (possibly called stack, but unrelated to the stack segment). No utility in the world can possibly fix that.

Comment: @n.m. OP is referring to an automatic variable array, not to the entire stack space.

Comment: Crypt of the NecroDancer is not going to be updated anymore, not even for the array issue? Sad :-( As for this, I would start dumping `gxtkInput::BeginUpdate()` (use the `disassemble` command) and see what is exactly breaking. If you are lucky, you will only need to modify a `sub esp, N` to a bigger value; plus maybe adjust the offsets in other instructions. If not, `gxtkInput::BeginUpdate()` is using the memory but not reserving it, and you will have to do the adjustment wherever that stack space was reserved.

Comment: Aye, NecroDancer is done according to the dev I spoke with (join their Discord to see full chat history). I am trying to run the game on my ITG2 dance arcade cabinet but the PIUIO kernel driver creates a joystick that is too big for the game to handle. I'll look into those things you mentioned. I really wish I could get my hands on that old patch file so I could study it.. If you feel so inclined, you coudl join the Discord and maybe help me in real time? :( <3

Comment: @Karai17 Nice! Give that a try first and see if you can get information about the function that crashes, the address of the memory that crashes, etc. It is a good exercise to learn some assembly (you have all symbols available, so you are lucky!). When you are more accustomed to the problem, copy the relevant pieces you have found here, and then we can see where you are and if you need more help, sounds good? :)

Comment: It looks like this is the array you want to enlarge: https://github.com/chrismingay/CM-XMAS-2012/blob/master/xmas.build/glfw/main.cpp#L2910 . My suggestion would be to use tool like IDA Pro to find BeginUpdate then look around where your buffer is located. But this is a tricky thing to do, as changing its size might require changing lots of other offsets - check here https://godbolt.org/z/wOyoXg and see how many things changes when buffer size changes. And this is with -O0 enabled.

Comment: another aproach would be to fix glfwGetJoystickButtons so it wont read more than 32 values, You can find this function source also on google, here http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/librealsense2/html/winmm__joystick_8c_source.html, it looks like this while : "while (*count < (int) jc.wNumButtons)" should be changed to "while (*count < (int) jc.wNumButtons && *count < 32 )"

Comment: I need all 48 buttons on my device, so I think I'd prefer to increase the buffer size than cull part of my device.

@Acorn https://hastebin.com/wukiqokoji.log I'm getting this error when I try to disassemble.

Comment: Here is a thought. NecroDancer ships with its own libraries such as `libglfw.so.2`. Perhaps it might be an available approach to patch that library instead, assuming they haven't made any changes to it themselves? Or would that array sizing bit be in the binary itself?

Comment: It looks like it is statically linked with gxtk (the game developer toolkit). The bug is in gxtk so you need to reverse engineer the executable. I would get the library sources, compile it as-is, tweak compilation flags until the assembly code of gxtkInput::BeginUpdate() matches exactly between the executable and the separately compiled library, then modify the automatic array definition in gxtkInput::BeginUpdate(), recompile, see what has changed (it could be just one assembly instruction) and make corresponding changes in the executable.

Comment: Update: I've disassembled the functionin question and annotated a few points but I am a beginner at best with assembly so if anyone coudl help me determine what I may need to change here, I'd be very thankful~

https://hastebin.com/dixajusixo.asm

note: there is a comparison in a loop for the value of `0x20` which is our 32. changing that to `0x40` is one part of the puzzle, but not the whole thing..

I also tried changing the `sub 0x5c` and `add 0x5c` to `0x7c` but at this point i am having memory access violations instead of stack overflows~

Comment: https://hastebin.com/uwejuvowat.asm intel syntax~